# How to use custom view with ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

So i have a problem, i'm building a 4 tabs app. For tab support i use ABS. It's all working fine. However there is one problem i hate. For setting icons in tab items i use that:

```
 tab1 = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
tab1.setTag("1");
tab1.setIcon(R.drawable.androidtopmenu01);
tab1.setTabListener(this);
getSupportActionBar().addTab(tab1);
```

So it adds new tab, no problem. But it also adds a lot of padding to each side of the image. So when i add 4 tabs they are wider than regular screen and i mean a lot so the 4 tab isn't seen at all. I know user can slide there, or when i pick tab 3 it automaticly slide right. But i want to remove those paddings so on a startup a user will see all 4 tabs. Or at least 3 and most of the 4.

Thank u all!

Comment: So no ideas? i'm trying to find in which xml is it defined but i cant find it neither :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i'm not certainly using ActionBarSherlock but it's probably about styles. So try to set correct tab style in library's value folder. I'm not so sure, but as i look out, it could be:

```
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabView" parent="Widget">
    <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/abs__tab_indicator_ab_holo</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">16dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">16dip</item>
</style>
```

try to reduce these paddings.

Comment: can u please tell me in which xml should i change it?

Comment: Great it works!!! Thank u werry much! So i give u 50 bounty for that, can u please just tell me why nobody knew that until i give bounty?

Comment: I don't know, i just see your question by chance... But i'm glad it works :)

Comment: Hm i find out that it doesn't remove paddings oh bigger screns, any idea on how to do that???

Comment: Not so sure, but there may be other styles to use on bigger screens. You should check it out.

Comment: Well it seams i'm really dumb. I can't find it. There are folders for xlarge but there is no styles.xml in it. There is only a few values but i can't make it work and i tried a lot of things by now...